# Harnack's inequality

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

PDE Evans, 2nd edition, Exercise 2.7

> Use Poisson's formula for the ball to prove
> $$r^{n-2} \frac{r-|x|}{(r+|x|)^{n-1}}u(0) \le u(x) \le r^{n-2} \frac{r+|x|}{(r-|x|)^{n-1}}u(0)$$
> whenever $u \in C^2(B^0(0,r)) \cap C(\partial B(0,r))$ is positive and harmonic in $B^0(0,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. This is an explicit form of Harnack's inequality.

My proof attempt is in the answer, but I would like to know if it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

Triangle inequality and reverse triangle inequality assert that
$$r-|x|\le|x-y|\le r+|x|$$ for all $x \in B^0(0,r)$ and $y \in \partial B(0,r)$ (which means $|y|=r$).

Now we appeal to Poisson's formula: $$u(x) = \frac{r^2-|x|^2}{n \alpha(n)r}\int_{\partial B(0,r)} \frac{g(y)}{|x-y|^n} dS(y)$$

Thus, \begin{align}
u(x) &\le \frac{r^2-|x|^2}{n \alpha(n)r}\int_{\partial B(0,r)} \frac{g(y)}{(r-|x|)^n} dS(y)  \\
&= r^{n-2} \frac{r+|x|}{(r-|x|)^{n-1}} \frac{1}{n \alpha(n)r^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(0,r)} g(y) \, dS(y) \\
&= r^{n-2} \frac{r+|x|}{(r-|x|)^{n-1}} u(0) \end{align}
and \begin{align}
u(x) &\ge \frac{r^2-|x|^2}{n \alpha(n)r}\int_{\partial B(0,r)} \frac{g(y)}{(r+|x|)^n} dS(y)  \\
&= r^{n-2} \frac{r-|x|}{(r+|x|)^{n-1}} \frac{1}{n \alpha(n)r^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(0,r)} g(y) \, dS(y) \\
&= r^{n-2} \frac{r-|x|}{(r+|x|)^{n-1}} u(0) \end{align}
Therefore, Harnack's inequality has been established, as desired.

Comment: When does equality holds? Is it only for $x=0$?